# How to use openssl passwd command from the openssl library?

Tags: c++, openssl

I would like to know if the openssl library include a function for `openssl passwd` command ? 
For example I would like to create a hashed password using sha512 with a custom salt, corresponding command is `openssl passwd -6 -salt xxxx password`.
I search in the documentation but I didn't find anything, always talking about the command but not about the library.
 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one function in the library, if you want to know what the [command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/passwd.html) is doing, it points you to it in the help:

> -5
>   -6
>
> Use the SHA256 / SHA512 based algorithms defined by Ulrich Drepper.
>   See https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt.

So it's using the openssl library to implement the SHA512 algorithm by Ulrich Drepper.

You can check out the source code [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/passwd.c) to see how it's done.  Look for the shacrypt function which is implementing the Ulrich Drepper algorithm using the openssl library.

Comment: Perfect thanks, the shacrypt function is what I was looking for!
So I tried to include it in my code but it uses the OPENSSL_zalloc function like so :
`if ((p_bytes = OPENSSL_zalloc(passwd_len)) == NULL)` [line 665](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/passwd.c#L665)

But in the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_zalloc.html) that function don't return anything so I have that error : _assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'_.

Any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like you are compiling c code with a C++ compiler...  You don't need to use OPENSSL_zalloc, you could just change it to new/delete.  I would take this is a example of how to implement this with openssl.  You should be able to simplify the code to just want you want to do removing openssl only code (like OPENSSL_zalloc for example).

Comment: Yes that was exactly this, trying to compiling for c++ and not for c. It was because of the implicit conversion from `void*` to `char*` that is working in c but not in c++ (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067956/11108779)). So I added a cast and it works perfectly, thanks!